# Can't grab value of after using strtok in CSV in C

Tags: c, csv

I'm trying to get a value from a CSV file and sum it to see if it passes a certain threshold. With the following code, I am able to print the values of the columns separately, such that if a line on the CSV file has "PTS,1,01/01/2020,400.00" it will print

```
PTS
1
01/01/2020
400.00
```

```
void total(char accnum[], char date[], char amt[]){
        size_t line = 0;
        char buf[100] = "";
        char *term = accnum;
        FILE *fp = fopen("record.csv","a+");
        int exist = 0;
        int cnt = 1;
        int sum = 0;
 while (fgets (buf, 100, fp)) {     /* read each line */
                if (strstr (buf, term)) {       /* test for term  */
                        char* token = strtok(buf, ",");
                        while (token != NULL) {
                                 printf("%s\n", token);
        cnt = cnt++;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
                        exist = 1;
                }
                if (strchr (buf, '\n')) line++; /* increment line */
        }
if(exist == 1){
        exit(1);
        }

        if (fp != stdin){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error, no user record %s\n", accnum);
                fclose(fp);
                exit(50);
        }

}
```

However, when I try to change it so that it adds the last value, it doesn't work, i.e.

```
while (token != NULL) {
                               if (cnt == 4){
                                int tmp = atof(token);
                                sum = sum + tmp;
                                printf("%lf\n", sum);
```

In my program it says that the increment is within the outer while loop, so I don't understand why it's not working.

PS sorry for improper indentation

Comment: Proper indentation really helps to see loop structure.  Since your question seems to revolve around confusion about which loop contains a particular statement, it seems unrealistic to ask for help without first fixing the indentation.

Comment: Please be more specific. "Doesn't work" is not very informative. Provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the input, expect output and actual output.

Comment: "sorry for improper indentation". If you are aware the indentation is not correct then why don't you just fix it so that others (and you) can read it clearly? The problem may even be more evident to you after you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- to read a file with the fopen function use the mode "r" instead of "a+"
- it is useful to check if fopen is successful and terminate with an error code if it is not
- arguments for the total function could be term and a pointer to double (the result)
- the function could return a bool indicating whether the term was found in the .csv file or not
- the sum seems to be a floating point type, so consider using double instead of int
- index variables normally start with 0 in C

So if one takes your code and modifies it slightly to the above points, it might look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


bool total(char *term, double *sum) {
    char buf[100] = "";
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("record.csv", "r")) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    bool exist = false;
    *sum = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {     /* read each line */
        if (strstr(buf, term)) {       /* test for term  */
            char *token = strtok(buf, ",");
            for (int cnt = 0; token != NULL; cnt++) {
                if (cnt == 3) {
                    double tmp = atof(token);
                    *sum = *sum + tmp;
                    printf("%lf\n", *sum);
                } else {
                    printf("%s\n", token);
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
            exist = true;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return exist;
}

int main(void) {
    double sum = 0;
    char *term = "PTS";
    if (total("PTS", &sum)) {
        printf("result: sum containing term %s is %lf\n", term, sum);
    } else {
        printf("Error, no user record %s\n", term);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

With this input:

```
PTS,1,01/01/2020,400.00
ZZZ,2,01/02/2020,400.00
PTS,3,01/03/2020,200.45
```

the output in the debug console would look like this:

```
PTS
1
01/01/2020
400.000000
PTS
3
01/03/2020
600.450000
result: sum containing term PTS is 600.450000
```